# Restrict direct access of sub-domain but allowed if requested from another specific domain

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have two domains.

- domain1.com
- domain2.com

I have to restrict direct access to `www.domain1.com/demo`

If i used `www.domain1.com/demo` as ifame or iframe wrapper menu in Joomla in domain2.com it should open. In fact it should only open on domain2

Comment: Have you already tried anything? Can you show it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *X-Frame-Options* flag configured on your domain1.com webserver.
It' allows you to define from which domains domain1.com could be rendered on iframe object using *ALLOW-FROM* value.
On your case you should configure on your's domain1.com webserver (example for Apache):

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM domain2.com
```

You have good explanation of how to configure webservers here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

**DISCLAIMER**: as you can read on the above link, Chrome and Safari do not support *ALLOW-FROM*, so please take this into account.